# Error installing SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, iis

I try to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows 8.

There is a problem on step 7 of Configuration Wizard:

> 11/04/2012 19:12:28 8 ERR Failed to provision the SharePoint Central
>   Administration Web Application. An exception of type
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was thrown. Additional
>   exception information: Filename:
>   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\34108\web.config Line
>   number: 25 Error: Defined copy of the partition
>   "system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler"
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800700B7): Filename:
>   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\34108\web.config Line
>   number: 25 Error: Defined copy of the partition
>   "system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler"

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Max, check the version of .NET you have installed. Sharepoint 2010 requires .NET 3.5 and does not support 4.0.

"SharePoint 2010 does not support access from .NET Framework 4 or being run in a .NET Framework 4 app domain. If you must support the .NET Framework 4, we recommend that you develop a web service that uses the .NET Framework 4 and then connect to it from SharePoint. All server-side customizations directly for SharePoint 2010 still need to be either the .NET Framework 3.5 or the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1."

This quote above is directly from the MSDN blog [click here to go to the full page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/14/net-framework-support-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> In my environment, the root cause is the SharePoing Web service has no
> permission to execute the Central Admin web application creation.
> To solve this error I used the following method.
>
> 1. Clear the cache by opening drive:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\Guid and then delete
>    all XML file and open cache.ini, then set the number to 1
> 2. open IIS and go to SharePoint Web Services, right click add permissions
> 3. add the domain user (I used domain admin) and grant full control
> 4. retrun the SharePoint wizard & finish the wizard

Taken from [Source](https://community.emc.com/people/TonyWu/blog/2012/07/27/install-sharepoint-2013-failed-with-error-message--failed-to-provision-the-sharepoint-central-administration-web-application)

Hope it helps ;)